# Webpack webpack.config.js vs webpack.config.babel.js file

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, babeljs

Can someone explain the difference between the webpack.config.js and  webpack.config.babel.js files?

What are the required changes needed to be done to change between those two?

Answer (score 1):

There are both Webpack Configuration files.
Look at the [Webpack Configuration doc](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/) and [Webpack Configuration Concept](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/configuration).

You can have multiple configuration in your project and when you want to execute one of them you can use the flag `--config CONFIG_FILE_NAME` like `webpack --config CONFIG_FILE_NAME`.

So in your case:

`webpack --config webpack.config.js` or `webpack --config webpack.config.babel.js`

Answer (score 0):

In case of `webpack.config.babel.js`, use ES6+

```js
import x from y;
```

rather than ES5

```js
var x = require(y);
```